# I am not getting output proper

Tags: python

I am supposed to compute the `sum` of `salaries` and `bonuses` for each employee mentioned in `salary.txt` I have written the following code but I didn't get the expected results where `salary`+`bonus` = `total`.

salary.txt

```
salary =
Ravindra Jadeja=117000
Ambati Rayudu=78000
M S Dhoni=150000
Axar Patel=10100
R Ashwin=130000
Ishant Sharma=135000
Ajinkya Rahane=134000
Shikhar Dhawan=124000
Bhuvneshwar Kumar=115000
Mohammed Shami=102000
Umesh Yadav=140000
Rohit Sharma=120000
Stuart Binny=111000
Suresh Raina=98000
Virat Kohli=135000

bonus =
M S Dhoni=15000
Virat Kohli=12500
Ajinkya Rahane=12500
Shikhar Dhawan=12500
Rohit Sharma=15000
Stuart Binny=15000
Suresh Raina=15000
Ravindra Jadeja=12500
Ambati Rayudu=15000
Axar Patel=9000
R Ashwin=13000
Bhuvneshwar Kumar=12500
Mohammed Shami=10000
Umesh Yadav=20000
Ishant Sharma=15000
```

example:

```
Ravindra Jadeja=117000 + Ravindra Jadeja=12500
```

example output:

```
Ravindra Jadeja: 129500
```

code:

```
name1 = []
name2 = []
global sal
import itertools
salary = []
salary2 = []
global rep , part
read = open("C:\Users\ishaan_sathe\Documents\chotu2.txt")
for lines in itertools.islice(read ,17 ,None):
    lines = lines.strip()
    lines = lines.replace("salary =",'')
    #print lines
    spl = lines.partition("=")
    part = spl[0] + spl[2]
    name1.append(spl[0])
    salary.append(spl[2])
read.close()
read = open("C:\Users\ishaan_sathe\Documents\chotu2.txt")

for line in itertools.islice(read , None):
    line = line.replace("bonus =",'')
    p = line.partition("=")
    f  = p[ 0]  + p[2]
    name2.append(p[0])
    salary2.append(p[2].strip())
#print salary
#print salary2

for y,z in zip(salary,salary2):
    for x in name1:
        for a in name2:
            print (x,a)
            print (y,z)
            if x == a:
                try:
                    sal = x + "total sal = " ,int (y) + int (z)
                    print sal
                except Exception as e:
                    print e
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure I understood you but I assume you want to sum up their salaries and bonuses?

```
salaries = {}
bonuses = {}

with open('salary.txt','r') as salary:
    section = 0
    for line in salary:
        line = line.strip()
        line = line.split("=")

        if line[0].strip() == "bonus": section = 0;continue
        elif line[0].strip() == "salary": section = 1;continue

        if line in (""," "): continue

        if section == 0:
            try: bonuses[line[0]] = line[1]
            except: pass
        elif section == 1:
            try: salaries[line[0]] = line[1]
            except: pass



totals = {}
for key, value in salaries.iteritems():
    try:
        totals[key] = int(bonuses.get(key, 0)) + int(value)
    except:
        pass

print totals
```

Salary.txt

```
salary =
Ravindra Jadeja=117000
Ambati Rayudu=78000
M S Dhoni=150000
Axar Patel=10100
R Ashwin=130000
Ishant Sharma=135000
Ajinkya Rahane=134000
Shikhar Dhawan=124000
Bhuvneshwar Kumar=115000
Mohammed Shami=102000
Umesh Yadav=140000
Rohit Sharma=120000
Stuart Binny=111000
Suresh Raina=98000
Virat Kohli=135000

bonus =
M S Dhoni=15000
Virat Kohli=12500
Ajinkya Rahane=12500
Shikhar Dhawan=12500
Rohit Sharma=15000
Stuart Binny=15000
Suresh Raina=15000
Ravindra Jadeja=12500
Ambati Rayudu=15000
Axar Patel=9000
R Ashwin=13000
Bhuvneshwar Kumar=12500
Mohammed Shami=10000
Umesh Yadav=20000
Ishant Sharma=15000
```

output:

```
{
    'Shikhar Dhawan': 136500,
    'Ajinkya Rahane': 146500,
    'Suresh Raina': 113000,
    'Ishant Sharma': 150000,
    'Stuart Binny': 126000,
    'Virat Kohli': 147500,
    'Ambati Rayudu': 93000,
    'Umesh Yadav': 160000,
    'Ravindra Jadeja': 129500,
    'Bhuvneshwar Kumar': 127500,
    'M S Dhoni': 165000,
    'Axar Patel': 19100,
    'R Ashwin': 143000,
    'Rohit Sharma': 135000,
    'Mohammed Shami': 112000
}
```

Comment: thanks but you have done it using 2 txt files I have to do it using only one txt file which salary and bonus are in same txt file .This is the problem i am getting confused

Comment: @ISHAANSATHE oh ok, will take a look into it. btw; are they in the same line ? let's say employee `Jamal=1500 + Jamal=500` ? Would you show the original file you have please.

Comment: thanks again I will share google drive link of the file you can find it there    https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CbHQoFwgjCFyc4Qm8jj7BXSzXVjpgzHA/view?usp=sharing you can find the file there

Comment: @ISHAANSATHE tested it ?